# How to get a matrix A*A*C from a matrix A*B*C and a matrix B*A*C by T.dot in theano

Tags: numpy, theano

I would like to get a matrix of `A*A*C` from a matrix `A*B*C` and a matrix `B*A*C` by `T.dot` or else operation in theano, where the `A`, `B`, `C` are dimensions.

Is there an easy way to make it?

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to say `A`, `B` and `C` are **dimensions**? If so, what does a matrix of dimension `A*A*C` mean?

Comment: In fact, i want to do dot between `A*B`and `B*A` , for each `Ci`.

Answer (score 0):

you should formulate this clearer, dot product is commutative so *a.b=b.a* and a *dot product is not defined for three vectors* ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Properties ) . i do not know what is your intention but possibly you are running into a limitation of neural networks here. **Neural networks are based on weighted sums** i.e. *a dot product is a weighted sum* ( https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/291680/can-any-one-explain-why-dot-product-is-used-in-neural-network-and-what-is-the-in ) likewise as *convolution is a weighted sum* ( https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4723/what-is-the-physical-meaning-of-the-convolution-of-two-signals )  and so neural nets are not easily able to calculate plain simple multiplicative relations between dimensions i.e. *xy* , cf https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/217703/can-deep-neural-network-approximate-multiplication-function-without-normalizatio